# Unnecessary Cloning of div while using checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to clone a div containing particular details of a user when I check the checkbox and press OK. It is doing fine when I select multiple users. However, when I add more users while the previous checkboxes are selected, I see more buttons that are cloned but the divs are not cloned. You might think it is because I have added `$div.remove();`. But when I remove it, I can see the div cloned on the right side but the values are fine. The last div has to be removed, but I am getting problems.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delivery-assignment-ok').click(function(){
      var totalamount = 0;
      countCheck = $("input[name='check']:checked").length;
    $.each($("input[name='check']:checked"), function(){            
                // alert(this.id);
                
          var data=this.id;
          // alert(data);
          var id=data.split(" ");
          // alert(id[0]);
          var $div = $('div[id^="deliverydata"]:last');
          
            var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
            
              // alert(num);
          if (this.value == "False") {

              this.value = "True";
            var $clone = $div.clone().prop('id', 'deliverydata'+num );
            $clone.find('#delivery_orderId').prop('name','delivery_orderId'+num);
            $clone.find('#delivery_orderId').val("").end();
            $clone.find('#delivery_order_city').prop('name','delivery_order_city'+num);
            $clone.find('#delivery_order_city').val("").end();
            $clone.find('#delivery_order_address').prop('name','delivery_order_address'+num);
            $clone.find('#delivery_order_address').val("").end();
            $div.find("#delivery_orderId").val(id[0]);
            $div.find("#delivery_order_city").val(id[1]);
            $div.find("#delivery_order_address").val(id[2]);
            $div.after($clone).append('<button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>');
         
            $div.children().next().css({
              'float':'right',
                  'position': 'relative',
                  'top': '30px'
              }) ;
               $div.children('.row.form-group').css({
              'width':'91%',
              'float':'left'
            });
          
        }
         
        });
      if (countCheck != 0) {
        var $div = $('div[id^="deliverydata"]:last');
        $div.remove();

      }

    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class=" list-group items">
   
    <table class="table table-striped table-search" id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="check"></th>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Receiver Address</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="1234 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="1234 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>1234</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="123 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="123 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="12 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="12 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="14 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="14 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="123456 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="123456 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>123456</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="1234567 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="1234567 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" value="False"></td>
          <td>1234567</td>
          <td>Kathmandu</td>
          <td>Koteshwor</td>
          <td>Rs. 3000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
          <input type="button" id="delivery-assignment-ok" name="delivery-assignment-ok" class="btn-primary ok" value="Assign Task">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="heading">
                    <h3>Other Details</h3>
                
                </div>
                       
                       
                            <div id="products">
                          <div id="deliverydata1">
                           <div class="row form-group">
                              <div class="col col-md-4">
                                 <label>Order ID</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="delivery_orderId1" class="form-control" id="delivery_orderId">
                              </div>
                              <div class="col col-md-4">
                                 <label>City</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="delivery_order_location1" class="form-control" id="delivery_order_city">
                              </div>
                                 <div class="col col-md-4">
                                 <label>Receiver Address</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="delivery_order_location1" class="form-control" id="delivery_order_address">
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                                        
                          </div>
                                  

                        </form>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

codesnippet is attached below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this a lot easier if you don't use id's in the records that has to be duplicated. In my opinion generating dynamic id's is bad because it's hard to use them as identifier.
For the inputs you can use name array by adding `[]` to the name. In the form the data will be send as an array.

Added event delegation to the delete buttons to make them work for all records, you could assign the function to the dummy object and use `clone(true)` too if you prefer.

I made an hidden dummy row that will be cloned and filled depending on the selected rows. A data attribute is used to match them against the table rows so data won't be deleted when adding rows.

As you can see this reduces the amount of code needed as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Make delete buttons work with event delegation
  $('#products').on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
    $(this).parents('.deliverydata').remove();
  });

  //When assigning tasks
  $('#delivery-assignment-ok').click(function() {
    //Loop over the tr elements
    $.each($("#myTable tr"), function() {
      $tableRow = $(this);
      $checkbox = $tableRow.find('.rowSelect');
      
      var checkboxId = $checkbox.attr('id');
      
      //If row is checked and not added yet then add it
      if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#products div[data-checkboxid="' + checkboxId + '"]').length === 0) {
          var $clone = $('#productrow_dummy .deliverydata').clone();
          //Set corresponding row checkbox id as a data attribute
          //For some reason jQuery.fn.data() doesn't seem to work on cloned objects, attr() works fine.)
          $clone.attr('data-checkboxid', checkboxId);
          //Set input values
          $clone.find('.delivery_orderId').val($tableRow.find('.orderId').text());
          $clone.find('.delivery_order_city').val($tableRow.find('.deliveryOrdeCity').text());
          $clone.find('.delivery_order_address').val($tableRow.find('.deliveryOrderAddress').text());
          //Append clone
          $clone.appendTo('#products');
        }
      }
      //Else remove when a corresponding element is found.
      else {
        $('#products div[data-checkboxid="' + checkboxId + '"]').remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#productrow_dummy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class=" list-group items">

  <table class="table table-striped table-search" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="check"></th>
      <th>Order ID</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Receiver Address</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="1234 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="1234 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">1234</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="123 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="123 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">123</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="12 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="12 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">12</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="14 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="14 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">14</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="123456 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="123456 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">123456</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelect" name="check" data-filter-item data-filter-name="1234567 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000" id="1234567 Kathmandu Koteshwor 3000"></td>
        <td class="orderId">1234567</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrdeCity">Kathmandu</td>
        <td class="deliveryOrderAddress">Koteshwor</td>
        <td>Rs. 3000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" id="delivery-assignment-ok" name="delivery-assignment-ok" class="btn-primary ok" value="Assign Task">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="heading">
      <h3>Other Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="products">

    </div>
    <div id="productrow_dummy">
      <div class="deliverydata">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col col-md-4">
            <label>Order ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery_orderId[]" class="form-cont## Heading ##rol delivery_orderId">
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-4">
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery_order_location[]" class="form-control delivery_order_city">
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-4">
            <label>Receiver Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="delivery_order_location[]" class="form-control delivery_order_address">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-delete">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I added the IDs so that it will be easier to clone.Yeah the code is much simpler than before and easy to understand.Thank You :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @samanaghimire I noticed I still had `clone(true)` in my example. I used that to test if it would solve the problem of the `data()` function not working on cloned objects but it didn't help. Removing this parameter should slightly improve the efficiency of the `clone()` function. If you use `true` as a parameter it also clones event handlers and some other things.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs some serious cleanup. It's a really bad design, you can't  remove the last item in `#products` because the next item will depend on it, but if you just hide it, it seems to do what you need. Try replacing

```
if (countCheck != 0) {
    var $div = $('div[id^="deliverydata"]:last');
    $div.remove();
}
```

with

```
if (countCheck != 0) {
    $('div[id^="deliverydata"]').show();
    $('div[id^="deliverydata"]:last').hide();
}
```

Comment: Also the cloned element contains elements with duplicated id's.

Comment: yeah it worked.I should have used hide() earlier but it got out of my mind.Thank you :)